# How can I use an alias for a CONCAT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I need to return an alias column `eventTitle` of which the content can be variable depending on whether another column's value is `null`. I also need to use the value of that alias to concatenate some other values to return another alias `title`.

I am running the following query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT
        CASE WHEN session.title IS NOT NULL
           THEN session.title
           ELSE course.title
        END AS eventTitle,
        CONCAT(eventTitle, "\n", session.city, ", ", session.state) AS title,
        FROM session
        LEFT JOIN course ON course.id = session.course_id';
```

I get the following error:

> Unknown column 'eventTitle' in 'field list'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't refer to column aliases in the same `SELECT` clause. Put it into a subquery. Also, instead of `CASE` you can use `IFNULL` (or the more standard `COALESCE`).

```
SELECT eventTitle, CONCAT(eventTitle, "\n", city, ", ", state) AS title
FROM (SELECT IFNULL(session.title, course.title) AS eventTitle, session.city, session.state
      FROM session
      LEFT JOIN course ON course.id = session.course_id) AS subquery
```

Or you could just use `IFNULL` twice in the same query.

```
SELECT IFNULL(session.title, course.title) AS eventTitle,
       CONCAT(IFNULL(session.title, course.title), "\n", session.city, ", ", session.state) AS title
FROM session
LEFT JOIN course ON course.id = session.course_id
```

BTW, I think you either have the null check or `LEFT JOIN` backwards. When you use `LEFT JOIN`, you get `NULL` in the columns from the *second* table when there's no match. So the column that will be `NULL` would be `course.title`, not `session.title`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately when I try to run that I get `Unknown column 'session.city' in 'field list'`

Comment: Sorry, fixed it. Need to return those columns from the subquery.

Comment: Yup, that definitely worked. I think the second approach is easier to follow. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I typically use the first method when the calculation is really complicated. If there were no `IFNULL` function, so I had to write the `CASE` expression, I would do it.